# Localization/Internationalization in Swift 2.0 / Xcode 7.2

Tags: swift, localization, internationalization

I'm stuck on getting started to localize my App.

I've already researched the web to this topic, only finding pretty old stuff.

So what have i done so far:

[Looking up on Apple's Guidelines. I should find sth in Xcode that looks kind of familiar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxnbE.png)

[But in Xcode it looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVx0.png)

I'm pretty sure there is only a small step needed to fix this, but i have no clue what setting i would have to make.

If necessary, I'm working with Xcode 7.2.1, Swift 2.0, and this app's deployment target is iOS 7.0

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

I think you selecting project target, You have to select project as show in Image below[image]

Comment: I knew it was something trivial like this. It did't show me the option because i had to click on the symbol on the top left of the upper red circle ("Hide project and target list"). Thank you very much for the correct answer